# Why are my values not updating on init (Angular + Electron)?

Tags: angular, electron

**setting.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-setting',
  templateUrl: './setting.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./setting.component.css']
})
export class SettingComponent implements OnInit {
  private primaryServer: string;
  private secondaryServer: string;

  constructor(
    private electron: ElectronService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.electron.ipcRenderer.send("asynchronous-message", {get: "settings"})
    this.electron.ipcRenderer.on("asynchronous-reply", (event, data) => {
      this.primaryServer = data.database.primary;
      this.secondaryServer = data.database.secondary;
    })
  }
}
```

**setting.component.html**

```
<p>{{primaryServer}}</p>
<p>{{secondaryServer}}</p>
```

My "primaryServer" and "secondaryServer" values do not show up when the page loads. however, when I click on the input or a random button for it, it shows up. How do I get them to show up on init?

Comment: Your code might run outside of Angulars zone and therefore Angular doesn't recognize it needs to run change detection. You can use `zone.run(() => { your code that updates the model here })` to force code back into the zone. If this works you can investigate further why it runs outside Angulars zone.

Comment: Are you sure that data received? Is it sync or async?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Change Detection Breaks Down with Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41254904/angular-2-change-detection-breaks-down-with-electron)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/zone.js/blob/master/NON-STANDARD-APIS.md#usage-1 may help you

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that worked. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 6):

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-setting',
  templateUrl: './setting.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./setting.component.css']
})
export class SettingComponent implements OnInit {
  private primaryServer: string;
  private secondaryServer: string;

  constructor(
    private electron: ElectronService,
    private zone: NgZone
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.electron.ipcRenderer.send("asynchronous-message", {get: "settings"})
    this.electron.ipcRenderer.on("asynchronous-reply", (event, data) => {
      this.zone.run(()=>{
        this.primaryServer = data.database.primary;
        this.secondaryServer = data.database.secondary;
      })
    })
  }
}
```

This is the changes I made for it to update properly as said by

> Your code might run outside of Angulars zone and therefore Angular doesn't recognize it needs to run change detection. You can use zone.run(() => { your code that updates the model here }) to force code back into the zone. If this works you can investigate further why it runs outside Angulars zone. – [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer)

Comment: Thank you for including the final result that worked for you based on your question, I think a lot of stack-overflow questions/answers could benefit from this format!