# Input value not updating after electron open folder dialog closes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

I have this component which I attach to an `input` to stylize it the way I want.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'input[ui-input]',
  template: '',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
})
export class InputComponent {}
```

I then use it in the html like below. I also have a button which I click that opens a folder selection also seen below.

```html
<ui-form-field *ngIf="home$ | async">
  <label ui-label>Default Project Location</label>
  <input ui-input [(ngModel)]="home" />
  <div ui-form-field-actions>
    <button ui-button-fab (click)="selectFolder()">
      <fa-icon [icon]="browseFolderIcon"></fa-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</ui-form-field>
```

The component that I have attached to this looks like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings',
  templateUrl: './settings.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings.component.scss'],
})
export class SettingsComponent {
  home = '';
  home$ = of(this.settings.get<string>('default-save-location')).pipe(
    tap(i => (this.home = i))
  )

  selectFolder() {
    this.electron
      .openFolder()
      .pipe(
        tap(i => console.log(i)),
        tap(i => (this.home = i))
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

When the component loads the home gets set and renders the value into the input. However, when `selectFolder()` runs, the new value gets logged to the console, but the template doesn't update unless I click inside of the `input` then click outside of the `input`.

I don't have `changeDetection` set on any of my components either so they are all using the default change detection strategy.

Not sure if it is relevant, but I have this in the electron service:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ElectronService {
  private home = new BehaviorSubject('/');
  home$ = this.home.pipe(switchMap(() => this.#getItem<string>('path', 'home')));

  openFolder() {
    return this.#getItem<{ filePaths: string[] }>('open-folder').pipe(
      map(i => i.filePaths?.[0] ?? ''),
      take(1)
    );
  }

  #getItem<T, U = unknown>(key: string, ...args: U[]) {
    return new Observable<T>(sub => {
      window.ipcRenderer.once(key, (e, v) => {
        sub.next(v);
        sub.complete();
      });
      window.ipcRenderer.send(key, ...args);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like I have to call `tap(() => this.cd.detectChanges())`, why do I need that why isn't it changing automatically?

Comment: I replaced your service by normal observables and it worked fine. Could you create a stackblitz link for the issue?

Comment: @jimmy So, I made a stackblitz, and it does work there, so maybe it has to do with electron opening a [dialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options) interfering with the lifecycle hooks.

Comment: could it be because I am attaching to `window.ipcRenderer` which is outside of the zone?

Comment: yup, you're right, this is a known issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481383/angular-electron-view-does-not-update-after-model-changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by creating a `preloader` in the electron main service with `contextIsolation`. I also added a dialog handler to handle opening of dialogs:

```js
let win: BrowserWindow;

app.on('ready', () => {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  });

  ipcMain.handle('dialog', (evt, method: any, ...params: any[]) => dialog[method](...params));
});
```

Next in the preloader, I added a context bridge to expose some functions to the renderer:

```js
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
  dialogOpen: (method: string, options: any) => ipcRenderer.invoke('dialog', method, options),
});
```

Next, within my renderer process I just need to call the`dialogOpen`  function:

```js
  openFolder() {
    return from(
      window.electron.dialogOpen('showOpenDialog', { properties: ['openDirectory'] })
    ).pipe(
      map(i => i.filePaths?.[0] ?? ''),
      take(1)
    );
  }
```

Not only does this fix the issue, but I no longer have to call `window.ipcRenderer.send()` and then create a listener to listen for a response. The function just returns a promise with the result!